# typo3 text and media open images as lightbox

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

is it possible to open a text and media image in a lightbox?

What I want is that all linked images in text & media automaticall open as a lightbox

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To globally enable Lightbox ("Enlarge on Click" checkbox which is 
available in the content element text & media), You can set default values for backend forms using **UserTS or PageTS configurations**.

You just need to write the below code there :

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.image_zoom = 1
```

This enables each new "text & media" content element's checkbox "Enlarge on Click" will be checked by default. So whenever any new text & media content added from backend have lightbox option is set by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have a constant for it in fluid_styled_content : `styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.lightboxEnabled = 1`.

Comment: does not have any effect on the links

Answer (score 2):

Class and rel attributes can be also helpful.
In your constans add falowing code:

```
styles.content {
    textmedia {
        linkWrap.newWindow = 0
        linkWrap.lightboxEnabled = 1
        linkWrap.lightboxCssClass = class--name
        linkWrap.lightboxRelAttribute = lightbox[{field:uid}]
    }
}
```

Comment: does not have any effect on the links